# SSL errors - .well-known

Tags: 7, .htaccess, ssl

I am seeing lot of SSL errors after enabling SSL for my site. 
Following is the common error related to the SSL configuration:

```
AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/xxxxxx/.well-known
```

Is this something related to any settings in our Drupal folder like creating "**.well-known**" folder or adjusting .htaccess settings or is it related to the Apache settings?

Answer (score 1):

That folder is needed by LetsEncrypt and is nothing to do with Drupal. For some details elsewhere on the SO network see https://serverfault.com/questions/796745/letsencrypt-do-i-need-to-keep-well-known-accessible-for-certificate-renewal

Comment: Ok. So, Can I ignore those error messages or if I create that folder in my root Drupal installation, what files should I add in that folder?

Comment: Please keep this site for questions about Drupal only, there are other resources out there for unrelated questions. Thanks